# What to do when you don't know what to do about something you see wrong / odd on SO?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I was going over the SO open questions to see if I could answer any, and when I was going through it I found some things that is rather irregular, or so it seems to me.
But I don't know what I should do.

**In this case**: [perfomance checking of system by using FreshDiagnose tool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2666661/109702)  (10K only)

I don't think it qualifies as a question, to be honest I barely understand it and the OP answer it himself. Is this fine? Or should I do something? Can I do something in a case like this?

**In this other question**: [Property getting error when ever assigning value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1845927/109702) (10K only)

I am not looking to go against the OP, I think he doesn't really have bad intentions or anything, although if you look at his answer and some of his questions his behavior is a bit erratic

But I don't know what would be the correct thing to do in this cases? And what if in future I find some other cases like this I would like to know what should I do?

Comment: _What to do when you don't know what to do ... ?_ You come here and ask.

Comment: Awwww my eyes burn after looking at the first question

Comment: First question: burninated.

Comment: Second question: Answer converted to comment.  You're welcome.  Next time, you can just flag the post using the Custom option, and put "Something doesn't look right here" in the box if you're not sure what the problem is, and we'll take a look at it.

Comment: Oh Cool, thank you guys! I will do that in the future! I just didn't know if it was correct to flag in such a situation.

Comment: @Dzyann Unlike some other sites, on Stack Exchange whenever you see *anything* wrong you should raise an appropriate flag (in time you'll come to understand each of the flags and their uses). And, as Robert said, if you don't quite know what's wrong just use a custom flag and explain as best you can. :)